# I am getting an error pop-up while signing up with google account in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am new to flutter and I am trying to sign users in with their google account. I am getting the following error popup while signing in with google.

[image]

this is code for google sign in.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSIn.signIn();   
final GoogleSignIn googleSIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
      'email'
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Please go through this google documentation and verify your app

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Comment: I am very very glad you've responded! Thanks I will  check ASAP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
  ],
);
```

then

```
 final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```